# Images are not loading in build version in one of my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build

I am working on my portfolio website with react and some of the images are not loading on the build version but it is also working fine on my local development server.

```
import cryptoImage from "./projectsImage/crypto4.png";
import wordIndexImage from "./projectsImage/Word Index.png";
import lcoImage from "./projectsImage/lco.png";

export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Crypto Stalker",
    img: cryptoImage,
    link: "https://crypto-stalker.netlify.app/",
    desc: "A crypto currency application to stalk all your favorite cryptocurrencies at one place including market cap, time gap and chart analysis.",
    tech: ["React", "Material UI", "Chart Js", "Redux", "Netlify"],
    gitlink: "https://github.com/codesabhi/crypto-stalker-app",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Word Index",
    img: wordIndexImage,
    link: "https://wordindex.netlify.app/",
    desc: "A dictionary app which supports twelve languages along with audio support also a progressive web app that is downloadable on respectable devices",
    tech: ["React", "Material UI", "Axios", "PWAs", "Netlify"],
    gitlink: "https://github.com/codesabhi/word-index",
  },
```

And here I am mapping all the above data including images in a different component.

```
const ProductCard = ({title,img,link,desc,tech,git}) => {

  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
      <>
    <div className="c">
      <div className="c-left">
        <div className="c-card bg"></div>
        <div className="c-cards">
          <a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" className="c-imglink"><img src={img} alt="" className="c-img" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I don't know why?
but it is all working nice in local development but not on the build version

Comment: What do you see in the `src` attribute for your image?  Can your browser resolve the url you have there?  Sounds like you have a relative link rather than an absolute one.

Comment: yes, the URL is working nice but the image is not showing in my build version.

Comment: which image is not loading ? only the wordIndexImage ? or both ?

Comment: both images are not loading on the build version and everything works well like URL and all.

Comment: @AbhishekYadav Could you show your project folder and files structure?

Comment: github repo:- https://github.com/codesabhi/abhishek-portfolio

Comment: @MarioG8 here my images are in projectsImage folder and I am gathering it in my data folder to make an array of objects then I am mapping it into another component. Do check out my github repo I have mentioned just above